# Tax Calculator - Python

Tags: python

**Question:**

Calculate income tax for the given income by adhering to the below rules:

| Taxable Income | Rate (%) |
| --- | --- |
| First $10,000 | 0 |
| Next $10,000 | 10% |
| The remaining | 20% |

**Solution (that I did):**

````
income = int(input('What is your income? '))
if income <= 10_000:`
    print('You have zero tax')
elif 10_000 < income <= 20_000:
    income_2 = (income - 10_000)*0.1
    print(f"Your tax amount to be paid is ${income_2}")
elif income > 20_000:
    income_3_1 = ((income - 10_000)*0.1)
    income_3_2 = ((income - 20_000)*0.2)
    income_3 = income_3_1 + income_3_2
    print(f"Your tax amount to be paid is ${income_3}")```
````

What mistake did I make? Where did my algo go wrong?

Comment: Your question doesn't explain the problem you are facing or the expected and current output. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @arulmr BTW, you can use `[ask]` and it will auto-expand to that link. Example: [ask]

Comment: @sawan could you please make the rule a bit clearer?

Comment: What's the expected output, what's the exact input? Looks alright as far as I can tell from the question

Comment: you are making him pay twice. first with 10% rate then with 20% rate. I think it's supposed to be 20% for more than 20000.

Comment: if he must pay the first 10000 after his initial 10000 at 10% rate then pay the rest at 20% rate, if he earned 25000, the first 10000 at 10% would be 1000 and the rest 5000 at 20% would be 1000 making his total tax 2000. So, income_3_1 should be a fixed value of 1000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple routine with test:

```
for income in [5000, 15000, 25000]:
    if income <= 10_000:
        tax = 0
    elif income <= 20_000: 
        tax = (income - 10_000) * 0.1              # 10% on income above 10K
    else:
        tax = (income-20_000) * 0.2 +  10_000*0.1  # 20% on income above 20K, plus tax on 10K of income below 20K

    print(f"For income {income}, You owe {tax} dollars in tax!" )
```

**Output**

```
For income 5000, You owe 0 dollars in tax!
For income 15000, You owe 500.0 dollars in tax!
For income 25000, You owe 2000.0 dollars in tax!
```